# Making torch data set error "cannot import name 'read_data_sets' from 'dataloader'"

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch

I'm trying to create my own torch dataset class and I ran into this problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "us_name_train.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dataloader.usname_dl import NameDataset
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataloader\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dataloader import read_data_sets
ImportError: cannot import name 'read_data_sets' from 'dataloader' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataloader\__init__.py)
```

I've seen people post about this problem, but I think mine is extra odd, because the solution is to change 'dataloader' to 'DataLoader' cause it's a typo that was supposedly fixed in 2018, but my file is actually called 'dataloader.py' in the torch library and when I look through the file I do see the 'read_data_sets' function.

[image]

Also when I do change 'import dataloader' to 'import DataLoader' it says it can't find the module, but with 'import dataloader' it finds the module just can't find the function 'read_data_sets.' Other people had this problem cause they created their own module called dataloader, but I definitely don't have anything named 'dataloader' in my project dir. Anyone else deal with this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by updating pytorch using

```
pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
```